# Returning structs in registers - ARM ABI in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, struct, arm

In the ARM ABI documentation I come across functions defined like:

```
__value_in_regs struct bar foo(int a, int b) {
    ...
}
```

but GCC(*4.3.3*) doesn't allow it and all I could find are references to some *RealView* compiler.
Is there any way of doing this from GCC?

I have tried -freg-struct-return but it doesn't make a difference. As it is an ABI I can't change the original programs, and returning a regular struct mangles the stack.

I would rather not using assembly for this if avoidable as it isn't otherwise necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Which ABI documentation are you reading?  The ARM AAPCS I'm reading doesn't have that keyword.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf

Comment: I did some googling and I see what's going on.  Can you just write a little bit of assembly code to thunk those calls?  Or does this happen a lot?

Comment: @jbcreix, no, you just need to write a little assembly shim to make the function call and then push the results on the stack and return.  You can leave everything else the same.

Comment: @jbcreix, it's the same problem.  Then you need to make your assembly shim/thunk code the public API, and call from that into your C code, pull the values *off* of the stack into registers and then return.  Same problem, just going the other direction.

Comment: Well that's not very optimal in the orders of magnitude scale. http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_CJAGGGGD.htm This compiler seems to be able to do it in C and C++, though I can't be sure it produces the needed code. This is why I asked if there is any GCC alternative.

Comment: Why not?  It should be like 10 instructions....

Comment: @Carl, well, it seems I was too worried, the overhead there is small enough. Turns out the library version is even slower. I am still not happy with needing assembly for this, but if there is no better solution I will take this route.

Comment: @jbcreix, using assembly is usually the only way to get around ABI compatibility issues.  If you're really set on not using assembly, I guess you could modify your copy of GCC to emit the code you're looking for.

Comment: @Carl, as I ended up using your solution, you might consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting as an answer by request:

If you have to generate a binary that will work with an ABI your compiler doesn't support, you're in for some trouble.  There's nothing you can do in C.  In this case, you'll need to fall back on assembly language programming and thunk the necessary calls.  There are two possibilities:

1. Calls from your binary into the other binary's ABI.
2. Calls from the other binary into your binary's ABI.

Both of these problems are solved similarly.  To call out from your code, you'll need to make shim functions in assembly that swizzle around the calling convention to match the external ABI, and then call the external functions from there.  The difference to your C code is that now to make external calls, you call your internal assembly routine, and it does whatever it needs to to call out externally, then puts the return value back in a format your C code will understand, and returns.

To support calls from the external binary *into* your code, you do the same thing, but in reverse.  The entry points to your binary will be little assembly routines that swizzle the external ABI into a format your C code can understand, call your internal function, then put the return values back into a format the external code understands, and return.

Sometimes there's just no good solution, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it for two registers by using "long long", as specified in "Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture" link given in this page.

```
long long test(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t d)
{
    long long ret;
    ret = a+b;
    ret <<= 32;
    ret |= c + d;
    return ret;
}
```

will be simply compiled as:

```
0002dbb8 <test>:
2dbb8:       1841            adds    r1, r0, r1
2dbba:       18d0            adds    r0, r2, r3
2dbbc:       4770            bx      lr
```

and the `ret & 0xFFFFFFFF` and `ret >> 32` in your calling function will be replaced seamlessly by r0 and r1.

It is even possible to do it for registers r0 to r3 by using "Containerized
vectors":

```
typedef uint32_t uint32x4_t __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

uint32x4_t test2(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t d)
{
    uint32x4_t ret = { a + 1, b + 2, c + 3, d + 4};
    // to access elements: ret[0], ret[1], ...
    return ret;
}
```

which is compiled as:

```
0002dbb8 <test2>:
2dbb8:       3001            adds    r0, #1
2dbba:       3102            adds    r1, #2
2dbbc:       3203            adds    r2, #3
2dbbe:       3304            adds    r3, #4
2dbc0:       4770            bx      lr
```

Note that it is referenced as a SIMD/NEON feature in the document above, but I just achieved it on a Cortex M0 in Thumb mode, without NEON support.

Answer (score 0):

The ["Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042b/IHI0042B_aapcs.pdf)
specifically says (section 5.4: Result Return):

"A Composite Type not larger than 4 bytes is returned in R0."

"A Composite Type larger than 4 bytes ... is stored in memory at an address passed as an extra argument when the function was called ... ."

I know that some CPUs have several different "standard" ABIs.
But I was under the impression that practically all compilers for the ARM used this same ABI.

Do you have any evidence that GCC *doesn't* use this standard ABI?

Would you mind posting a link to any information on a ABI for the ARM that is different from this standard ABI -- the ABI used by the caller, or the called, or both?

Comment: Frankly, I don't remember, and I don't have the machine ready to check it now, but rereading my own words, no, gcc didn't follow that at the time or else, the code would have generated the correct assembly without `__value_in_regs` and I wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you can try using the `pcs` [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

```
struct bar foo(int a, int b) __attribute__((pcs("aapcs")));
struct bar foo(int a, int b) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This behaviour isn't specified in the AAPCS; it's a RVCT feature.