# ARM ABI wants to return result in registers, using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

Similar to the question here:
 [Returning structs in registers - ARM ABI in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901488/returning-structs-in-registers-arm-abi-in-gcc)

I was hoping I could tell GCC that the result is in registered (leave them alone) and leave the stack untouched, but it only "mostly" works, which I suspect is just luck.

The when compiling, I am left with undefined reference __aeabi_uldivmod(), which I am trying to supplement. There is a nice _uldivmod.S from google, but I was looking at a C solution.

Currently, I am trying something like:

```
res = __udivdi3(u, v);
mod = __umoddi3(u, v);
{
register uint32_t r0 asm("r0") = (res&0xFFFFFFFF);
register uint32_t r1 asm("r1") = (res>>32);
register uint32_t r2 asm("r2") = (mod&0xFFFFFFFF);
register uint32_t r3 asm("r3") = (mod>>32);

printk("r0 %08X : %08X : %08X : %08X\n",r0, r1, r2, r3);

asm volatile(""
             : "=r"(r0), "=r"(r1), "=r"(r2),"=r"(r3)  // output             
             : "r"(r0), "r"(r1), "r"(r2), "r"(r3));   // input              
return r0;
}

kernel: [ 3457.959207] r0 00000000 : 00000000 : 00000000 : 70000000
udivdi3: 7000000000000000/7000000080000000 != 000000000000003f rem dfffffe080000000
```

__udivi3() and __umoddi3() are standard C functions.

Not only am I returning something (stack) but it does not always leave r1-r3 alone, since I think the "output field" of the ASM statment, only affects the ASM statment itself, not the function declaration of my __aeabi_uldivmod.

gcc 4.4.3

Can it not be done?

Comment: Your use of inline assembly is problematic in multiple ways. First, you're declaring specifically-assigned register variables yet call a function (`printk`) afterwards where those registers are used for argument passing - and which will _clobber_ them as they're not in the preserved list. Second, the `asm` statement specifies the same registers for input / output yet doesn't use the `"+r"` specification which indicates this to the compiler. Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do there, and why (if you need specific reg bindings) you won't do a pure assembly function ?

Comment: My apologies, I did add printk in desperation to see if the vars were at least set correct, which they are.

The problem comes from ARM's ABI for uldivmod:

```A pair of (unsigned) long longs is returned in {{r0,r1},{r2,r3}}, the quotient in {r0,r1}, and the remainder in {r2,r3}. The description above is written using ARM-specific function prototype notation, though no prototype need be read by any compiler. (In the table above, think of __value_in_regs as a structured comment).```

Comment: So, My implementation of uldivmod, must return the result in r0/r1/r2/r3. With ARMCC you would use __value_in_regs, but this appears to not exist in GCC. I was exploring the idea of convincing GCC to return the result in r0-r3 using the ASM directive.

Comment: With gcc, if you insist on using inline assembly for this, then the suggestion would be to give the function `attribute((naked))` - that'd not create prologues/epilogues for you and you're able to return in any which way you consider appropriate. "return" in that sense meaning actual assembly `bx lr` or equivalent; the C `return` at the very end is only needed to silence the compiler warning about not returning a value from a non-void function, you wouldn't actually _use_ that.

Comment: I had noticed that C "return" was messing things up. I made the function be void, and using this inline:


`register uint32_t r0 asm("r0") = (res&0xFFFFFFFF);
register uint32_t r1 asm("r1") = (res>>32);
register uint32_t r2 asm("r2") = (mod&0xFFFFFFFF);
register uint32_t r3 asm("r3") = (mod>>32);
asm volatile(""
    : "+r"(r0), "+r"(r1), "+r"(r2),"+r"(r3)  //  output             
    : "r"(r0), "r"(r1), "r"(r2), "r"(r3));   // input              
return;//r0;
`

Comment: (wow, that's unreadable) and it does actually work. Both result and remainder. But is that just luck? I will read up on `naked` functions as well, and test that out. I will have to forgo declaring local variables and calling functions though.